# To call a method of a fragment from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 Fragments for an activity. e.g. FragmentA and FragmentB. I have a public method MethodA in FragmentA. Now I want to use MethodA in FragmentB of FragmentA.

Comment: try like this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: @NoName this link is used for methods in activity and fragment but i want between fragments

Comment: where you added that fragments? in pager? mention clearly...

Comment: @NoName I am using both fragments in same Activity. Now I want to used the same method in one Fragment into another

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to do is Create Interface and implement your activity with that interface. Now initilize that interface in FragmentB and on click of something you have to call the method of interface wherever you want to call method of FragmentB. Now in your activity callback method just call the method of FragmentB with the help of object

Comment: how you will get that interface reference in fragement.

Comment: Interface1 interfaceObj = (Interface1) getActivity();

Comment: some times after orientation changes getActivity() will becomes null.

Comment: call this method after onActivityCreated()

Comment: of course you have given correct answer but you should also tell about getting the object. the best way to get the Activity Object inside the fragment is onAttach(Activity activity).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get list of all fragment and then child fragment then check your fragment instance.

```
for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments())
                    {
                        for (Fragment fragment1 : fragment.getFragmentManager().getFragments())
                        {
                            if (fragment1 instanceof Shoppingcart)
                            {
                                FragmentA mFragmentA = ((FragmentA) fragment1);
                                mFragmentA.A();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```